OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found when importing torch in YOLO script
I am trying to run a YOLO inference script using the ultralytics package in a Python virtual environment on my Windows 10 x64 system. However, I am encountering the following error when trying to import torch:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\apoor\Desktop\football_analysis\yolo_inference.py", line 1, in <module>
    import torch
  File "C:\Users\apoor\Desktop\football_analysis\cv_env\Lib\site-packages\torch\__init__.py", line 148, in <module>
    raise err
OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found. Error loading "C:\Users\apoor\Desktop\football_analysis\cv_env\Lib\site-packages\torch\lib\fbgemm.dll" or one of its dependencies.

Things I've tried so far:
Verified Installation of Packages: Reinstalled both ultralytics and torch using pip.
Checked Visual C++ Redistributables: Installed both x86 and x64 versions of the Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributables.
Activated Virtual Environment: Ensured that my virtual environment is activated correctly.
Set Python Interpreter: Selected the correct Python interpreter in VS Code
.

I had the same issue and found a fix: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78794748/10549172

The issue is that pytorch needs a specific DLL file and cannot find it.  It looks like you are using a virtual environment and pip as the package management tool. My guess is that the pypi version of pytorch does not include the DLL file it needs and relies on it being in the system.
A work around is to use conda as your environment and package management tool.  Conda package are different than pypi packages in that they typically include everything you need to run them in an isolated environment.  To install conda, go here: https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/ and download the latest version of miniconda for your operating system and install it.
This will add a shortcut your start menu in Windows to the "Anaconda Prompt".  Open that and you will be in the base conda environment.  To create a new environment, use:
conda create --name my-env python pytorch torchvision pandas <any other package you need>

Then drop into the environment using:
conda activate my-env

and try running your script.

my problem initiate by ultralytics and tensorflow its installed on python 3.12. I solved it uninstall native torch, then install torch from here https://pytorch.org/get-started/previous-versions/.
ROCM 6.0 (Linux only)
pip install torch==2.3.1 torchvision==0.18.1 torchaudio==2.3.1 --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/rocm6.0
CUDA 11.8
pip install torch==2.3.1 torchvision==0.18.1 torchaudio==2.3.1 --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu118
CUDA 12.1
pip install torch==2.3.1 torchvision==0.18.1 torchaudio==2.3.1 --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu121
CPU only
pip install torch==2.3.1 torchvision==0.18.1 torchaudio==2.3.1 --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu
